# Share connection strings between web apps in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

In Azure there's the possibility of storing the Connection Strings in the "Application Settings" section of the online portal. This overrides the value in the web.config, which is very useful.

The issue is that I am having multiple web apps in Azure that all use the same connection string, so I would like to have one common entry in the portal where I can set this and all the apps should use it. Is this intentionally not possible because is bad practice, have I missed it or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application settings are always defined for the IIS instance running behind the scenes for your application. If you have multiple web apps, then they need to have the same settings duplicated.

However, what you are looking for is known as the [External Configuration Store pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/external-configuration-store).

## External Configuration Store pattern

This pattern describes the situation where you got multiple applications where each need to access the same configuration. In this pattern, this is accomplished by saving the settings externally, in e.g. an Azure Storage blob.

[image: External Configuration Store pattern]

From the above link, highlighted your described usecase:

> ### When to use this pattern
>
> This pattern is useful for:
>
> - **Configuration settings that are shared between multiple applications and application instances, or where a standard configuration must be
>     enforced across multiple applications and application instances.**
> - A standard configuration system that doesn't support all of the required configuration settings, such as storing images or complex
>     data types.
> - As a complementary store for some of the settings for applications, perhaps allowing applications to override some or all of the
>     centrally-stored settings.
> - As a way to simplify administration of multiple applications, and optionally for monitoring use of configuration settings by logging
>     some or all types of access to the configuration store.

Comment: This would definitely work, though it seems a bit complicated. Wouldn't it be great to have an "Applications settings" section in the Resource group under which all these apps are running where to set the connection string once?

Comment: In my opinion, this is a good suggestion that MS could consider when developing new features for Azure App Service. In cases like this, best is to suggest this as a new feature. There's https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps where new suggestions can be made.